# classify keywords into fields

Tags: keyword, text-classification

Is there an existing resource (dictionary/database or something else) that can help classify keywords into different categories of fields and can be integrated in programming? For example, when seeing "arson", classify it as "Crime"; when seeing "injection", classify it as "Health Care", something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a so trivial problem. In fact, it's a standard question in Machine Learning, so there isn't a dirty easy solution.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: This involves "teaching" a machine how to identify correlation, and in Machine learning it's done by feeding a large data set and let the machine classify each data point in some abstract data space. You can think of it as curve-fitting, only on a higher dimension. I'm not aware of publicly aware and easy to use resource for that since it's highly technical.